# How to load properties file from jar to javascript code in mirth environment

Tags: javascript, jar, import, mirth

Hai I am trying to read properties file from `jar` to my `javascript` code in **mirth environment**.  I wrote js code in transformer.

I kept jar file in lib folder.

It is showing exception like:

> The choice of Java method java.io.FileInputStream matching JavaScript
>   argument types (null) is ambiguous; candidate methods are:
>   FileInputStream(java.lang.String)    FileInputStream(java.io.File)
>   FileInputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor)
>   (com.mirth.connect.server.MirthJavascriptTransformerException)

Below is the code:

```
importPackage(Packages.logproperties.*);
var prop=new Packages.java.util.Properties();
var fis=new     Packages.java.io.FileInputStream(Packages.java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Logs.properties"));
prop.load(fis);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message is looks like you are calling `FileInputStream` with `null`.

That means that `Packages.java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Logs.properties")` is returning `null`.

Try using the absolute path to the file that you want to read, e.g.

```
var fis=new Packages.java.io.FileInputStream("/full/path/to/Logs.properties");
```